# Proof from Fuzzy Intersection

Tags: fuzzy-set

While solving exercise of **Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications** by *George J Klir* and *Bo Yuan*, I came across this question:-

Let $i$ be a t - norm such that

$$i(a, b + c) = i(a, b) + i(a, c)$$

for all $a, b, c \in [0, 1]$ and $b + c \leq 1$. Show that $i$ must be the algebraic product, i.e., $i(a, b) = ab$ for all $a, b \in [0, 1]$.

I have literally no insights about proving this. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove the statement for $i(a,b)$ where $b$ is rational
Since the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, you can use monotonicity of $t$-norms to generalize this to all $b\in [0,1]$.

To see what we will be doing, I will give an example for $b = 2/3$. In this case, we have
$$
a = i(a, 1) = i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)
=i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right) + i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)+i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)
=3\cdot i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
Dividing either side by $3$, we see that
$$
i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{a}{3}
$$
But then,
$$
i(a,b) = i\left(a, \frac{2}{3}\right)
=i\left(a, \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right)
=i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)+i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)
=2\cdot i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
Since $i\left(a, \frac{1}{3}\right) = a/3$, the above is precisely
$$
i(a,b) = 2\cdot \frac{a}{3} = a\cdot \frac{2}{3} = ab
$$

We now prove the statement where $b$ is any rational in $[0,1]$.
If $b=p/q$ for integers $p,q$ with $0\leq p\leq q$, $q\neq 0$. Then by the assumption $i(a, b + c) = i(a, b) + i(a, c)$ we have
$$
a = i(a,1) = qi\left(a, \frac{1}{q}\right) \implies i\left(a, \frac{1}{q}\right)=\frac{a}{q}
$$
Using again the assumption $i(a, b + c) = i(a, b) + i(a, c)$ we have
$$
i(a,b) 
= i\left(1, \frac{p}{q}\right)
= p\cdot i\left(1, \frac{1}{q}\right)
=p\cdot\frac{a}{q} = ab
$$

Now, suppose that $b$ is irrational. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists rational number $b_1, b_2$ such that
$$
b_1\leq b \leq b_2
$$
and
$$
b_2-b < \frac{1}{n}, \quad b-b_1 < \frac{1}{n}
$$
By monotonicity of $t$-norms,
$$
i(a,b_1) \leq i(a,b) \leq i(a,b_2)
$$
Since $b_1, b_2$ are rationals, the above is precisely
$$
ab_1 \leq i(a,b) \leq ab_2
$$
Now, we may write
$$
ab_1 = a(b_1+b-b) = ab - a(b-b_1) \quad\text{and}\quad ab_2 = ab + a(b_2-b)
$$
So, we have
$$
ab - a(b-b_1) \leq i(a,b) \leq ab + a(b_2-b)
$$
Subtracting $ab$ on either side yields
$$
- a(b-b_1) \leq i(a,b)-ab \leq a(b_2-b)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lvert i(a,b)-ab\rvert \leq \max\{a(b-b_1), a(b_2-b)\}
$$
Since $b_2-b < \frac{1}{n}$ and $b-b_1 < \frac{1}{n}$, the above is bounded by
$$
\lvert i(a,b)-ab\rvert \leq \max\{a(b-b_1), a(b_2-b)\} \leq a\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
where the last inequality holds since $0\leq a \leq 1$.

So, we conclude that
$$
\lvert i(a,b)-ab\rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
But this means that $i(a,b)=ab$ as desired.

Comment: Could you explain more what have you done? It is becoming really confusing to understand.

Comment: I added an example in my answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: And what about the irrationals? How can we use the density to prove the same for irrationals?

Comment: I wrote in detail how you can use the density of rationals. Is there anything still missing?

Comment: No. It is absolutely correct! I could have never thought of this approach to prove it! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76231/discussion-between-aniruddha-deshmukh-and-mathuser-notprime).